# React server side rendering is not updating after client side route change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

For the first time, the server side is refreshed, but the next time, only the client side is changed as usual, and the server does not change.

For example, with each refresh or typing of the address in the browser, the server also changes and works, but if I switch between pages on the client side with react router, the server does not change.

what is the problem?

**#server/server.js**

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from '../src/App';

const PORT = 5000;
const app = express();

const router = express.Router();
app.use('/build', express.static('build'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (/\.js|\.css|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg/.test(req.path)) {
    res.redirect('/build' + req.path);
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const context = {};
  const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  const indexFile = path.resolve('./build/index.html');
  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Something went wrong:", err);
      return res.status(500).send("Oops, better luck next time!");
    }

    return res.send(data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${app}</div>`));
  });
});

router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'), { maxAge: '10d' }));

app.use(router);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`SSR running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

**#server/index.js**

```
require('ignore-styles');

require('@babel/register')({
    ignore: [/(node_module)/],
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    plugins: ['@babel/transform-runtime'],
});

require('./server');
```

**#index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your Server Side Rendering setup. This is what's going on under the hood.

When you first type and enter the URL for a route of the application or you refresh the browser tab it hits the server and loads the `index.html` file rendered on the server-side with the help of `renderToString`.

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(...)`
```

Then `index.html` is viewed and is hydrated (attaching event handlers...etc) to this skeleton HTML file.

Note that you load the `index.html` from the build folder and replace only the div with root as the id. After building the app it adds js resources need to change the `DOM` (these resources are actually your frontend logic you wrote for your app) and this is required for `client-side` rendering. If you check the `index.html` it has the following script tags to load them.

```
...
<script src="/static/js/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.chunk.js">
...
```

When you go to another route by clicking a link inside your app. It does not hit the server again and it starts to execute js attached from the client bundle as I said above. Client-side js does the routing of the app properly. That's why it's not hitting your server. This is the expected nature of an `isomorphic web application`(Behaves the same on the server-side or client-side). And after that, if you refresh the browser that again loads the `index.html` from the server.

Comment: What exactly should I do?
Please help with more details. Thank you.

Comment: @behi, I think you did server rendering setup for SEO purposes or to improve the performance of the site. You have done it correctly and I gave the explanation for the question you have asked.

Comment: @behi, If this cleared your doubts, can you mark it as the answer? Thanks!